# Chrome extension produces "Invalid Signature" or "Invalid Public Key" on own hosting

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have two Chrome extensions written for in office use, they work fine as unpacked extensions imported locally, and fine as packed extensions installed from my own vserver.

However, when I deploy them to the production servers, trying to install one creates an alert saying "Invalid Signature", while the other produces an "Invalid Public Key" alert.

```
{
    "name": "Ext name",
    "description": "Some desc",
    "version": "1.1",
    "update_url": "http://[url]/extensions/updates.xml",
    "options_page": "options.html",
    "icons": {
        "128": "icon128.png" 
    },
    "permissions": ["contextMenus"],
    "background_page": "page.html",
    "homepage_url": "http://[url]/admin/browser.php"
}
```

Same for the other one, different descriptions etc (but no options page). I'v tried repacking them to generate new keys with no success.

Dont think its relevant, but this is the update xml referenced.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<gupdate xmlns='http://www.google.com/update2/response' protocol='2.0'>
  <app appid='<app1_id>'>
    <updatecheck codebase='http://[url]/extensions/extension1.crx' version='1.2' />
  </app>
  <app appid='<app2_id>'>
    <updatecheck codebase='http://[url]/admin/extensions/extension2.crx' version='1.1' />
  </app>
</gupdate>
```

I'm probably missing something very obvious here, but im a bit a bit stumped.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Self-signed certs are invalid in some browsers now. Either turn this off (I think you can turn this check off) or buy a cert from an authority.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks interval, but turns out this was a bit of a simple mistake on my part. When the extension was being pushed to production, it was being done so as a unicode file, not binary. Issue was caused by cvs (well, by me using it wrong :) ).

Don't know why I got different errors for each but pushing it as binary fixed both.